# SlickGrid DataView set colspan using value from row

Tags: object, slickgrid, dataview

I am trying to implement an updating colspan on certain items in a SlickGrid:

This part of the code works fine:

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {

  if (0 == 0) {
    return {
      "columns": {
        "heading": {
          "colspan": "*"
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
      "columns": {
        "heading": {
          "colspan": 1
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

It give all items a colspan as expected, but i want to get the value within the "highlight" column and use that to determine if the "heading" column gets a colspan applied. This needs to update every time the checkbox in the highlight column is clicked. So i need to get the value of the "highlight" column on that row.

If i run this:

```
  console.log(dataView.getItem(row));
```

I get multiple items like this:

```
Object {id: "id_5", highlight: 1, heading: "voluptatem", quoted: 0…}
```

But if I run this:

```
  console.log(dataView.getItem(row).highlight);
```

I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'highlight' of undefined
```

My question is, am I going about this the right way, and if so, how do I get the value of the cell in the "highlight" column and the "row" row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to wrap the current if statement in another if statement:

```
if (typeof data[row] != "undefined") {
  //original if
}
```

to make sure the row actually existed

Comment: great, yeah I was going to say that the error indicates not that the property doesn't exist (that would return ```undefined```), but rather that the whole row doesn't exist.